# Is it possible to have a dynamic method parameter if something in the method requires the parameter to use the "ref" keyword?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parameter-passing, ref

I've been working on a platformer game in Unity, and I have a lot of different types of horizontal movement, all of which are executed with the Mathf.SmoothDamp function. Everything in my game works as intended, but after trying to clean up some cluttered code tonight I ran into some issues with part of smoothdamp's functionality, specifically its requirement to use the **ref** keyword.

```
Mathf.SmoothDamp(float current, float target, ref float currentVelocity, float smoothTime)
```

The way my code has been structured for weeks is that I have a function that sets my horizontal velocity based on different if statements and their associated bools, but this has caused me to have to rewrite many blocks of code very similarly, with the only minor differences usually being the **ref float currentVelocity** and **smooth time** variables.

```
public void SetHorizontalForce(float x)
{
    if (State.IsJumpBoosted && xForce != 0) //Smooths out horizontal movement force when jump boosted left or right (also defines air control when horizontally jump boosted)
    {
        velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velocity.x, x + xForce, ref velocityXSmoothingLeft, Parameters.xForceJumpSmoothing);
    }

    else if (State.Launch)
    {
        velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velocity.x, Abilities.LaunchVelocity, ref launchVelocitySmoothing, Abilities.LaunchSmoothing);
    }

    else
    {
        if (smoothXForceMovement) //Smooths out horizontal boost movement when landing, so the character doesn't stop abruptly
        {
            velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velocity.x, x, ref velocityXSmoothing, Parameters.xForceLandSmoothing);
        }

        if (PlayerInput.DirectionalInput.x != 0) //Otherwise move as normal
        {
            if (PlayerInput.DirectionalInput.x > 0)
            {
                velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velocity.x, x, ref velocityXSmoothingLeft,
                    (State.IsCollidingBelow) ? Parameters.accelerationTimeGrounded : Parameters.accelerationTimeAirborne);
            }

            else if (PlayerInput.DirectionalInput.x < 0)
            {
                velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velocity.x, x, ref velocityXSmoothingRight,
                    (State.IsCollidingBelow) ? Parameters.accelerationTimeGrounded : Parameters.accelerationTimeAirborne);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems unnecessarily redundant, so I wanted to change my function to take in parameters:

```
public void SetHorizontalForce(float x, float velocityXSmoothing, float smoothTime)
{
velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velocity.x, x, ref velocityXSmoothing, smoothTime);
}
```

I'd then call this method as needed in other parts of my code, subbing in the necessary variables to make everything work properly again.

```
public void Launch() 
{
    CharacterController2D.SetHorizontalForce(airplaneVelocity, launchVelocityXSmoothing, launchSmoothTime);

    StartCoroutine(LaunchResetTimer());
}
```

This looks like it should work, but no matter how many different ways I tried to rewrite my code nothing ever worked the same again; in fact, my character was barely able to move at all. It wasn't until I removed the **float velocityXSmoothing** parameter and hard set it in my SetHorizontalForce function that things started feeling better.

However, if each distinct kind of movement doesn't have its own ref float currentVelocity value, SmoothDamp appears to "cheat," and doesn't respond to the smooth time as you'd expect. (Just to clarify, I found that having separate smoothing times for moving left and right caused those values to lerp by the smooth time almost exactly; using a single smoothing float caused the values to lerp faster, and did not feel as responsive to input.)

Am I using ref incorrectly? Is it even possible to use it as a parameter like this? I also tried adding **ref** in SetHorizontalForce's smoothing parameter, but this did not work.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with us.

Comment: You have to pass `velocityXSmoothing` by `ref` also in your `SetHorizontalForce` function.

Comment: I believe I tried this and was unsuccessful. It seemed like the logical thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: short answer**:

do

```
private float _velocityXSmoothing = 10f; // You will need to set that to a value that suits you, I used 10f arbitrarily

public void SetHorizontalForce(float x, float smoothTime)
{
    velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velocity.x, x, ref _velocityXSmoothing, smoothTime);
}
```

---

**Long answer**

This will require some understanding of the c# language.

The [ref keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) means that the value is **passed by reference**. Reference type objects in c# are passed by reference by default, meaning that if you pass them as argument and edit them, the edit won't disappear when the function returns. On the other hand, value types objects (like `struct` and primitive types such as float) are **passed by value** by default, meaning that the value is copied. the **ref** keyword is used to force a primitive type to be passed by reference. Look at the example below:

```
private void Start()  
{
    float val = 1f;
    Debug.Log("start with: " + val)
    FuncByValue(val); // This will print val + 3, but not change val in the Start method
    Debug.Log("after FuncByValue: " + val)
    FuncByRef(val); // This will print val + 10, and the change affects val also in this Start method
    Debug.Log("after FuncByRef: " + val)
}

private void FuncByValue(float val) // here, val is a COPY of the argument. like another variable with the same value
{
    val = val + 3;
    Debug.Log("by value: " + val)
}

private void FuncByRef(ref float val) // Here, val is exactly the same variable as the argument
{
    val = val + 10;
    Debug.Log("by ref: " + val)
}
```

In this example, the FuncByRef function will change the value of vall, so the output will be

> start with: 1
>
> by value: 4
>
> after FuncByValue: 1
>
> by ref: 11
>
> after FuncByRef: 11

So back to your code, when you do:

```
public void SetHorizontalForce(float x, float velocityXSmoothing, float smoothTime)
{
    velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velocity.x, x, ref velocityXSmoothing, smoothTime);
}
```

You pass a velocity by ref, meaning that the SmoothDamp function will **modify** is. This is noted in the [doc of SmoothDamp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html):

> currentVelocity   The current velocity, this value is modified by the function every time you call it.

The reason for this is that SmoothDamp expect you to **keep the modified value** so you can give it back the next time you call SmoothDamp so it continues with the effect. In your code, since your function gets the velocity by value, you don't keep the value that was modified by SmoothDamp. What you can do to make it work, instead of using a ref, is saving the `velocityXSmoothing` as a class variable so you keep it between each call:

```
private float _velocityXSmoothing = 10f; // You will need to set that to a value that suits you, I used 10f arbitrarily

public void SetHorizontalForce(float x, float smoothTime)
{
    velocity.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(velocity.x, x, ref _velocityXSmoothing, smoothTime);
}
```

Now the `_velocityXSmoothing` will be kept between each call and will be properly updated by the SmoothDamp function